# Error: Attempting to inject an unknown injection: 'service:i18n'

Tags: ember.js, internationalization, ember-i18n

i have the following Problem with ember-i18n:

```
Error: Attempting to inject an unknown injection: 'service:i18n'
at Registry.validateInjections (ember.debug.js:2303)
at ember.debug.js:1538
at runInDebug (ember.debug.js:5813)
at Object.runInDebug (ember.debug.js:17396)
at instantiate (ember.debug.js:1532)
at lookup (ember.debug.js:1385)
at Container.lookup (ember.debug.js:1304)
at Class.lookup (ember.debug.js:32564)
at Class._internalGetHandler (router-ext.js:107)
at Class._getHandlerForEngine (router-ext.js:84)
```

I use the ember-i18n plugin in an ember engine. My i18n initializers `addon/instance-initializers/i18n.js`:

```
export default {
name: 'i18n',

initialize: function(applicationInstance) {
    const i18nService = applicationInstance.lookup('service:i18n');
    i18nService.set('defaultLocale', window.I18n.defaultLocale);
    i18nService.set('locale', window.I18n.locale);
}
};
```

In my index route (`routes/index.js`) i have the following code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
i18n: Ember.inject.service(),

actions: {
    didTransition() {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
            console.log(this.get('i18n').t('error_empty_user_data'));
            // ....
        });
    }
}
});
```

How can I declare the i18n service?

I use the ember-18n 4.5.0 Version and the 2.10.0 ember-cli Version.

Answer (score 1):

The initializer should run after `i18n` one.

```
export default {
  name: 'i18n',
  after: ['ember-i18n'],

  initialize: function(applicationInstance) {
    const i18nService = applicationInstance.lookup('service:i18n');
    i18nService.set('defaultLocale', window.I18n.defaultLocale);
    i18nService.set('locale', window.I18n.locale);
  }
};
```